# Component architecture and the use of a DI container?

Tags: .net, oop, architecture, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an FTP utility responsible for the usual FTP stuff: put file, get file, etc.  As part of our infrastructure, we require components to retrieve their configuration from a component implementing an IConfiguration interface and to log their entries to a component implementing an ILogger interface.  Note that ftp host is described via a logicalHost name (e.g. someFtpSite) which matches to a section in the configuration file containing the host name, user id and password.  So my interface and class definition was created like this:

```
public interface IFtpUtility
{
    void PutFile(string sourceFileAndPath, string targetFileAndPath, string logicalHost);
}

public class FtpUtility : IFtpUtility
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public FtpUtility(ILogger logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    // IFtpUtility implementation follows
}
```

My intent with this signature was to only require logicalHost name when an action is required (such as PutFile) hence provision for it on the PutFile method itself.

This layout lends itself very well to be used with an IoC container like Unity.  We would have the following code:

```
UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();
UnityContainer.RegisterType<IConfiguration, ConfigurationProvider>();
UnityContainer.RegisterType<ILogger, LoggingProvider>();
UnityContainer.RegisterType<IFtpUtility, FtpUtility>();
```

When later I needed to use the FtpUtility, I would rely on the container for appropriate resolution:

```
IFtpUtility ftpUtility = UnityContainer.Resolve<FtpUtility>();
```

Now a colleague suggested to me that logicalHost name should be a parameter on the constructor since without it, none of the functions can execute and it is, more or less, associated with a specific instance of FtpUtility.  We would only be communicating with one FTP server per invocation.  So I gladly changed the constructor to include logicalHost name and that broke my IoC container resolution. 
See, while IConfiguration and ILogger can be associated with a specific implementation, logicalHost is specific to an instance and we don't know it until the time that the instance will be created.  Now I could argue that such a change would change my IoC Container usage and therefore I could not implement it, etc. but this is too weak of an argument (I find).  So here are the questions:

- From an architectural point of view, is placing the logicalHost on the constructor a good thing or not?
- Is logicalHost name a required construction parameter without which FtpUtility cannot function and as such, should be part of the constructor?
- Is there a way to resolve this with Unity?  If the constructor contained a third parameter of logicalHost, is there an overload to Resolve<>() that would allow me to supply the value of the third parameter at the time of resolution rather than having it registered with the container ahead of time?
- Am I trying to resolve a problem where there isn't one?  Is the use of an IoC Container an overkill in this situation which rather than help, complicates matters?  After all, I am still using IoC pattern - just that it cannot be resolved with an IoC container automatically or cleanly?

Comment: Perhaps it is a typo, but why do you resolve `FtpUtility` instead of `IFtpUtility`?

Answer (score 1):

1,2. From an abstraction point of view, having the hostname in the constructor is logical and an ideal place.

3,4. In my own personal opinion, resolving the hostname via unity is a little overkill, but entirely possible. An easier option would be the instantiate this is your unity config and extract the hostname from a standard app/web.config, similar to below (an MVC implementation);

```
 container.RegisterType<IFtpUtility, FtpUtility>(
      new InjectionConstructor(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Hostname"]));
```

This decouples things nicely and still allows you to configure that setting as required.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion but this approach is not possible since we are dealing with multiple hosts and the host itself is determined by the caller of the FtpUtility, hence a request for a specific logical host.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of resolving `IFtpUtility` directly, you could resolve `IFtpUtilityFactory`, with the following definition:

```
interface IFtpUtilityFactory
{
    IFtpUtility Create(string logicalHost);
}
```

Any given FTP utility implementation has a corresponding factory implementation. It's effectively a surrogate constructor with a generic interface, that can supply required parameters later than resolution time.

Comment: This is a nice solution that clearly separates IFtpUtility resolution from resolution of an instance for a specific instance but...aren't we building here a canon to kill a fly?

Comment: I suppose you could see it that way (another interface, plus a class which is just a fancy way of invoking `new`), but then on the other hand, I don't think it's a huge amount of either code or extra complexity in this case. I don't know Unity, but it's possible that it has facilities to make implementing this pattern easier, along the lines of [Ninject's providers](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Providers,-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context).